# Django: model.objects.create() changes the previous model.objects.filter()'s resultset

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a simple model named Keyword:

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
```

I'm trying to do bulk_create, but the bulk data may contain already existing keywords, therefore  I do the operation in two steps. First fetch the existing keywords, then bulk_create new keywords. Following is a small example of what I do in the process:

```
In [12]: t = ["aaaa", "dene"]

In [16]: existing = Keyword.objects.filter(name__in=t).all()

In [17]: new = set(t).difference(list(existing.values_list("name", flat=True)))                                

In [18]: new
Out[18]: {'aaaa'}

In [19]: existing
Out[19]: [<Keyword: dene>]

In [20]: created = Keyword.objects.bulk_create([Keyword(name=name) for name in new])                           

In [21]: created
Out[21]: [<Keyword: aaaa>]

In [22]: existing
Out[22]: [<Keyword: aaaa>, <Keyword: dene>]
```

Both bulk_create and create updates the previous filter's resultset. This is most probably a bug, but I may also be missing some point here. Is there anything wrong in my implementation?

Django version is 1.5.3.

Comment: so the problem is that existing shows 2 results instead of 1? it seems it is re-evaluating filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django querysets are evaluated lazily, when the values are actually retrieved. If you want to maintain the same sequence of models then you will need to pass them to e.g. the `list` constructor in order to firm them up.

```
existinglist = list(existing)
```

Comment: Ah my bad. I thought existing.values_list in [17] was already evaluating the queryset. Thank you.

Comment: @hinoglu: It was. But then it got evaluated again in 19, and then in 22.

Comment: Confused then. I may have lost the track on details of django's orm and evaluation. IIRC django did not reevaluate the resultset if it was already evaluated and the value of evaluation is used and this  seems to be completely wrong then?